# DROP SCHEMA fails on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I get this error every time I try and run `DROP SCHEMA dbname`.

`Error Code: 1010. Error dropping database (can't rmdir './dbname', errno: 39)`

I used to be able to drop schemas fine. My authentication is set up properly, I can create new schemas and select from my existing database. I have tried restarting the database instance. I just can't drop it.

Comment: Please contact us at cloud-sql@google.com with your instance name and steps (commands used) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just emailed in.

Comment: I also have this problem.  Did you find a resolution?  The auto-response from Cloud-sql@google.com indicates they will ignore any requests for help.